# Перенести определенное количество файлов в новую папку. Windows

Tags: windows, файлы, cmd, консоль, bat

**Есть несколько тысяч jpg файлов с порядковыми номерами. Надо перенести каждые 394 файла в отдельную, новую папку.**

Заранее извиняюсь если это не подходящий ресурс для подробного вопроса. Но если гуглить, то дороги ведут сюда.

Answer (score 0):

В общем сам нашел. Не знаю нормальный ли он. С задачей справляется но зачем-то убивает проводник.

```css
@Echo Off
If /I Not "%__CD__%"=="%~dp0" PushD "%~dp0" 2>Nul||Exit/B
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe >nul
taskkill /f /im SearchIndexer.exe >nul
sc stop WSearch >nul
sc config WSearch start= disabled >nul

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "DirN=-1"

:Check_DirN
Set/A "DirN+=1"
If Exist "%DirN%" GoTo Check_DirN
cls
echo Moving files to Directory %DirN%...
Set "limit=2999"
MD "%DirN%"
For %%A In (*.html) Do (
    RoboCopy . "%DirN%" "%%A" /MOV 1>NUL
    Set/A "limit-=1"
    If !limit! Lss 0 GoTo Check_DirN
)
Echo(Task Done!

start explorer.exe
start SearchIndexer.exe
sc config WSearch start= delayed-auto >nul
sc start WSearch >nul
Timeout -1 1>Nul
```

Comment: Остановка Wsearch и Проводника всего лишь для ускорения процесса и избежания блокировок перемещаемых файлов